# ListView and custom SurfaceView in same fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, surfaceview

I'm writing a custom SurfaceView implementation:

`CustomSurfaceView.java`:

```
public class CustomSurfaceView extends SurfaceView {
  private void init() { }

  // ...
}
```

I want to call `CustomSurfaceView` from a fragment, `myFragment`. Every example I can find on the web does this by

```
class myFragment extends Fragment {
  // ...

  public View onCreateView() {
    return new CustomSurfaceView(getActivity());
  }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that I also have a ListView, `myList`, in `myFragment`. It works like this:

`my_fragment.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout>
  <ListView id="@+id/my_list"/>
  <SurfaceView id="@+id/custom_surface_view"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

`myFragment.java`:

```
class myFragment extends Fragment {
  // ...

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

    myList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_list);

    return view;
  }
}
```

That configuration, without the `CustomSurfaceView`, works fine.

Then, I tried adding after `myList = ...`:

```
customSurfaceView = (CustomSurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_surface_view);
```

which results in an `Unexpected cast to CustomSurfaceView: layout tag was SurfaceView`.

If in my xml layout file I change `<SurfaceView/>` to `<com.example.CustomSurfaceView/>`, I get a crash on runtime (`Binary XML : Error inflating class com.example.CustomSurfaceView`).

So my question is this: what am I doing wrong, and which is the proper, working way to include both a `ListView` and `CustomSurfaceView` in the same `myFragment`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I hadn't defined by constructors to the proper specification.

Adding this code to `CustomSurfaceView.java` removed the `error inflating` crash:

```
public CustomSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
}
```